# How to create a function that can be called to display multiple bar graphs with JQplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I would like to create a function that can be called multiple times within an `HTML` page so I can display multiple stacked bar graphs.  They can't all be in the same chart because I need a bunch of other content between them.

My first thought was to just write the function and pass data to it as I need to create the bars.  I tried the below but for some reason is gives me an error of `No plot target specified`.

I am also not sure if this would be the best or most efficient way to accomplish this.

Thanks to anyone taking a look at this!

I thought each time I needed a bar I would just insert the below in the HTML

```
<script>
    var id ='bar_one';  //I also tried document.getElementById('bar_one');
    var data1 = [[12, 1]];
    var data2 = [[5, 1]];
    var data3 = [[3, 1]];
    barBuilder(id, data1, data2, data3);
</script>
<div id='bar_one' style="height:75px;width:500px; "></div>
```

External JavaScript file

```
 function barBuilder(id, data1, data2, data3){  



        var options = {
            animate: true,
            animateReplot: true,
            stackSeries: true,
            seriesColors:['#007f00', '#00b200', '#00ff00'],
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: {show: true,location: 'w'},
                rendererOptions: { 
                    barMargin: 13,
                    barDirection: 'horizontal'},
            },
            axesDefaults:{
                tickOptions: {textColor: 'black'}
            },
            axes:{
                yaxis:{renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    showTicks: false,
                    tickOptions: {showGridline:false, showMark:false}
                },
                xaxis:{showTicks:false,
                       show: false,
                       tickOptions:{showGridline: false},
                       rendererOptions:{drawBaseline:false}
                }
            },
            grid:{
                background:'transparent',
                drawBorder: false,
                shadow: false}
        };
         $.jqplot(id, [data1,data2,data2],options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plot graph in a div with id 'bar_one' but each time you call it to plot different graphs in the same div, so a better option would be to use **for loop** for dynamically creating div and passing graph values to jqplot object and appending **for** loop variable to the id's (inorder to create unique id for each div) created with different data.